# How to detect which project package is being displayed to the user on android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm developing an app that aims to monitor the usage time of apps and their type.

and I'm having difficulty finding the solution to know which application is open to the user at certain times...
I would like to know if there is any way to apply this...

example in practice:
my monitor app is always running in the background, and it has some alarms that go off at certain times of the day and raises a broadcast. at that moment that my broadcast that got up I would like to put some code snippet that shows which application at that moment is active for the user, for example if at that moment the instagram is being displayed, I want my app to find its package on the device which would be: com.instagram.android or if it was facebook it would find the package com.facebook.katana

technically I'm building an app that will be system and with admin privileges, and that won't go to the playstore so if there is any code for it I can implement it.

Comment: Fortunately, this has been impractical for quite some time, for privacy and security reasons. You can get historical data [via `UsageStatsManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager).

Comment: technically I'm building an app that will be system and with admin privileges, and that won't go to the playstore so if there is any code for it I can implement it.